# How to make Python driver script exit, while streaming remains working in Spark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

My `Scala` program starts streaming from `Kafka` to database and exit to command shell. Streaming continues working, and it's "application" is visible on `Spark` page.

My `Scala` program looks like this

```
val ssc = SparkHelper.getStreamingContext(spark, checkpointDir)
val dataFlowStream = KafkaHelper.getKafkaStream[DataFlow, DataFlowDeserializer](ssc, Topics.dataFlowTopic, config.getString("trackrecordsmetrics.kafka.group-id"), classOf[DataFlowDeserializer])

...

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

When I am starting it it writes:

```
21/04/08 08:58:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'driverClient' on port 32841.
21/04/08 08:58:54 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to sparkmaster/IPADDRESS:7077 after 22 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
21/04/08 08:58:54 INFO ClientEndpoint: ... waiting before polling master for driver state
21/04/08 08:58:54 INFO ClientEndpoint: Driver successfully submitted as driver-20210408085854-0016
21/04/08 08:58:59 INFO ClientEndpoint: State of driver-20210408085854-0016 is RUNNING
21/04/08 08:58:59 INFO ClientEndpoint: Driver running on IPADDRESS:45233 (worker-20210405082522-IPADDRESS-45233)
21/04/08 08:58:59 INFO ClientEndpoint: spark-submit not configured to wait for completion, exiting spark-submit JVM.
21/04/08 08:58:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/04/08 08:58:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-105e3428-ba75-47ca-9d3b-20aa48a45898
```

And then it exits. I still can see it's application on Spark page and see effects of it's work. I.e. driver exits while application keep working.

Contrary,

when I am running similar Python script, it works only while script is working. The end of my script is similar

```
query = df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode('update') \
    .foreachBatch(write_data_frame) \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

If I press `Ctrl-C` script ends and streaming stops. If I remove line `query.awaitTermination()`, streaming is never starts.

Is it possible to submit python scrpt so that it remains running there?

I am submitting Python script with

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.1,org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.7.2 MYSCRIPT.py
```

I can't specify `cluster` mode, because it is not supported for `Python`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Neither Python or Scala with `awaitTermination` shouldn't exit and you need to leave the process running for streaming to work... Cluster deploy mode should work fine with pyspark

Comment: Okay, how to exit, but continue streaming?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Scala program also has `awaitTermination` call, but it exits somehow. This is also what I need to understand.

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200388/how-to-exit-spark-submit-after-the-submission
--conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false